# Change language for whole Android application activities from Setting activity

Tags: android, multilingual

I'm trying to build a very simple application to test the multi language subject, the application should also recognize the language of the device , but also there is a way to change the language from another activity.

I'm using the languages folders, so if the user language is suite to one of the supported languages, it will take the right one.

The problem start when I'm trying to change it from 'Setting' activity.

I have a spinner that include the supported languages, after selecting new language, the current activity should be close and the language of both activities should be changed.

I saw a couple of examples on web' but no one help me here.

This is my XML code (just include a sippner and text):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.MES.yo.ActLanguageSettings">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="@string/Choose_Language" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/change_language" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnlanguage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the code for changing the language:

```
public void changeLang(String lang)
    {
        if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
         return;
        myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        saveLocale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
        android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
        config.locale = myLocale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    private void saveLocale(String lang)
    {
        String langPref = "Language";
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(langPref, lang);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

And for each activity I'm calling to "onConfigurationChanged" method like this:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Locale locale = new Locale(GVC.getLanguage());
    newConfig.locale = locale;
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

The Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.MES.yo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:name=".GlobalVarClass"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:configChanges="locale">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActLanguageSettings"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_act_language_settings" 
            android:configChanges="locale">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.MES.MySperm.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is doesn't work at all for me.

I tried also to change the language like this:

```
public void setLocale(String lang) {
            GVC.setLanguage(lang);
            myLocale = new Locale(lang);
            Resources res = getResources();
            DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
            Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
            conf.locale = myLocale;
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
            Intent refresh = new Intent(this, ActLanguageSettings.class);
            startActivity(refresh);
            finish();
    }
```

here the language was changed, but not for all other activities, Is there a rule of thumb for how to do it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code to change the language...

```
                    Locale locale = new Locale("ar");
                    Locale.setDefault(locale);
                    Configuration config = new Configuration();
                    config.locale = locale;
                    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                    settings.edit().putString("locale", "ar").commit();
                    this.finish();
                    Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(refresh);
```

And in each activity's onCreate and Onresume Methods you have to do somthing like this..

```
if (settings.getString("locale","").equals("en")) {
        Locale locale = new Locale("en");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        settings.edit().putString("locale", "en").commit();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, but I'm already tried this as you can see at my last code in the question, it works but only for the current activity and if I press back to the previous one the language there stay the same

Comment: What type is settings parameter?

Comment: it is shared preferance... settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
like this

Comment: @Rishad Appat it does not work for all activities!would you please help??

Comment: `settings.getString("locale",null).equals("en")` this really hurts my eyes! at least make `""` the default value...

Answer (score 0):

If you want @Rishad's Answer to work you have to do this before you set contentView I means before below line of code on all activities' `oncreate()` method

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name);
```

If you want not to do it again and again you can make a method in Java class and call it in your activities. 
Alternatively you can do it in the application class that will work for all of your activities. 
Make a new Java class and extend it with `Application`

```
public class MyApp extends Application
```

then add this code in on create of that class and override method `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` here is the complete code of this class

```
package com.qemasoft.alhabibshop.app;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Locale;

import static com.qemasoft.alhabibshop.app.AppConstants.LANGUAGE_KEY;

/**
 * Created by Inzimam Tariq on 1/17/2018.
 */

public class MyApp extends Application {

    private Locale locale;
    private static Context context;

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getBaseContext();

            changeLocale(context);

    }

    public void changeLocale(Context context) {
        Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        String lang = Preferences
                .getSharedPreferenceString(this, LANGUAGE_KEY, "ar");
        Log.e("MyApp", "language in MyApp = " + lang);
        if (!(config.locale.getLanguage().equals(lang))) {
            locale = new Locale(lang);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            config.locale = locale;
            Log.e("MyApp", "Inside if = " + lang);
            context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (locale != null) {
            newConfig.locale = locale;
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            context.getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
    }

}
```

After you have this class in your project override the below method in MainActivity

```
@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
    }
```

Now everything is working :)
**Note:** don't forget to add this application class in manifest, find the tag in manifest that start like

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApp"
```

Here replace your application class name mine is MyApp so I have it in Manifest.

**Important Note:** The only drawback of this code is the changes would not appear unless you restart the app.

Answer (score 0):

use this code in your base activity or main activity.

```
public static void switchLocal(Context context, String lcode, Activity activity) {
        if (lcode.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            return;
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        Locale locale = new Locale(lcode);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        android.content.res.Configuration config = new 
        android.content.res.Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
//restart base activaty 
        activity.finish();
        activity.startActivity(activity.getIntent());
    }
```